# Craft HTTP GET on Mac to get file

Tags: mac, download, http, wget

So I'm trying to download a file on my mac but the requirements to get the file are very strict:

```
Username:                testx
Password:                testing123
Authorization

You can craft the HTTP GET request using a tool such as Fiddler and then use this request in your own custom solution.

- You cannot pass the username and password in via the URL or access the feed through a browser.

- The outgoing HTTP GET request header must contain the Basic Authorization key-value.

For example: 

User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: test.test.com
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic ZmVlALCzABI6VEKABCDzdHIzM3I=
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

On a mac, what solution or program can I use to get this file. I've tried crafting a wget request but I can't get it working. Fiddler doesn't seem to be available on the mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple case to solve. With Wget:

```
wget --user=testx --password=testing123 --auth-no-challenge example.com
```

creates the following HTTP Request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.16.3.42-5666-dirty (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Authorization: Basic dGVzdHg6dGVzdGluZzEyMw==
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

This looks pretty much like what you were asking for.